# Saving image to documents directory with overwrite

Tags: swift, photo, nsfilemanager

I am capturing a photo with the device camera and saving it to the Documents directory with a specific filename. However, if a file of the same name already exists then the file is not saved. How can I simply overwrite a file of the same name, or if it does exist, delete it first? I'd prefer the first option.

```
let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

// Create the destination file URL for saving
let fileURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(photoFilename)

if let data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0),
    !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path) {
    do {
        // Write the image data
        try data.write(to: fileURL)
    } catch {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "OOPS!", message: "Couldnt save the image!", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true)
    }
}
print("not saved")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`write(to` overwrites data by default but **you** prevent it by checking if the file exists.

Just remove the check

```
let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

// Create the destination file URL for saving
let fileURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(photoFilename)

if let data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0) {
    do {
        // Write the image data
        try data.write(to: fileURL)
    } catch {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "OOPS!", message: "Couldnt save the image!", preferredStyle: .alert)
         alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
         self.present(alert, animated: true)
    }
} else {
    print("not saved")
}
```